# Pipe two different outputs into a command that takes two inputs

Tags: bash, shell, unix, pipe

It seems like this should be pretty easy but it's not intuitive to me how to do it.  I have two files and I want to diff their first columns (this is an example, I'm sure there are other ways to do this).  So I might do `cut -d, -f1 file1 > tmp1`, `cut -d, -f1 file2 > tmp2` and then `diff tmp1 tmp2`.  But I want to do it without using the tmp files.

An example of the sort of thing I'm expecting would be `((cut -d, -f1 file1), (cut -d, -f1 file2)) > diff` but this is not real code.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Good news! You can use [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) in bash:

```
diff <(cut -d, -f1 file1) <(cut -d, -f1 file2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this is:

```
cut -d, -f1 file1 | diff - <(cut -d, -f1 file2)
```